# java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: IS_SECURITY_ENABLED

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, jetty, maven-jetty-plugin

I want to deploy a service to 2 servers. I succeed on one server, but failed on the other one. In fact, I try my best to make their environments same. The error log is as following:

```
2013-01-21 22:08:18.178:WARN:oejuc.AbstractLifeCycle:FAILED jsp: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: IS_SECURITY_ENABLED
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: IS_SECURITY_ENABLED
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JspRuntimeContext.<init>(JspRuntimeContext.java:197)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.init(JspServlet.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:492)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:312)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:776)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1213)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:699)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:454)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:183)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:491)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:142)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:604)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:535)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:398)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:552)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:227)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AggregateLifeCycle.doStart(AggregateLifeCycle.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1215)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1138)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:602)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:82)
```

Thanks for any kind of help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> ```
> java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: IS_SECURITY_ENABLED
> ```

This is part of one of Jasper JSP compiler's internal classes. This error suggests that you (or Maven) have for some reason included the Jasper JSP compiler JAR files in webapp's `/WEB-INF/lib` folder while those JAR files are supposed to be already provided by the target container (which is Jetty in your case).

This way it would only work if your webapp contains Jasper JAR files of **exactly** the same version as the target container has. But, after all, this is not the right approach. Those Jasper JAR files do not belong in the webapp's `/WEB-INF/lib`. They are supposed to be *already* provided by the target container. You need to get rid of them in the webapp's `/WEB-INF/lib`.

I'm no Maven hero, but, to the point, you need to tell it to not include the Jasper JAR files in the `/WEB-INF/lib` folder of the built WAR. You can do that by setting their [dependency scope](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope) to `provided`.

Comment: Hello @BalusC, thanks for your answer. In fact, I copy the entire project from the server which normally run to the new server, problem still exist on the new one. BTW, the 2 servers get the same java version. [java version "1.6.0_25", Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_25-b06), Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b11, mixed mode)]

Comment: As answered, cleanup your runtime classpath to get rid of the rogue Jasper JSP compiler JAR file(s). Look in the `/WEB-INF/lib` folder of the built WAR file. It should not contain any container-specific JAR files.